# Loop trough multi-dimensional array and select the items

Tags: javascript

I would like to select the elements in a multi-dimensional array with the mouse, but I am doing something wrong and hope someone can help me.

I add this values to the array (EDITED)

```
xPosition.push(0);
xPosition.push(20);
xPosition.push(40);
xPosition.push(60);

row = [,];
row.push(10);
column.push(row);
row = [,];
row.push(10);
column.push(row);
row = [,];
row.push(10);
row.push(20);
row.push(30);
column.push(row);
row.push(10);
column.push(row);

id.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  var x = e.x-id.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var y = e.y-id.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < column[i].length; j++) {
      if (x >= xPosition[i] && x <= xPosition[i]+10 && y >= column[j] && y <= column[j]+10) {
        alert(j);
      }
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: what is `0, 0`?

Comment: The values for the array.

Comment: Does your code compiles ? What do you mean by 'with the mouse' ?

Comment: @Treycos yes but it shows me the wrong "index". With Mouse I mean the MouseDown event.

Comment: @Andy yes this is correct.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the element by using the mouse coordinates ? Why not make an HTML object for each cell and use the onClick event ? How is your table rendered ?

Comment: Where are the values of `x` and `y` declared?

Comment: Why is there a third coord marked as `40` at position 1,1? What does that represent?

Comment: `something = 1,2,3` is not proper syntax and will simply assign the first value (in this case 1) to the variable

Comment: The values and syntax are correct. Also when I use this it will be return the correct values. My problem is only with selecting the index with the MouseDown. alert("Values[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + column[i][j]);

Comment: I add simple this way the values: row = [,];
row.push(value);
column.push(row);

Comment: @JCss See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441565/how-to-make-javascript-display-the-index-of-the-table-the-user-is-mouse-clicking

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong? What are you expecting and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide more information in your code. So, I hope it will help you.

```js
var column = new Array(4);

for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
 column[i] = new Array(4);
}
 xPosition = [,];
xPosition.push(0);
xPosition.push(20);
xPosition.push(40);
xPosition.push(60);

row = [,];
row.push(10);
column.push(row);
row = [,];
row.push(10);
column.push(row);
row = [,];
row.push(10);
row.push(20);
row.push(30);
column.push(row);
row.push(10);
column.push(row);

function mouseDown() {
  var x = document.getElementById('myP').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var y =document.getElementById('myP').getBoundingClientRect().top;
  for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < column[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(x,y,j);
      if (x >= xPosition[i] && x <= xPosition[i]+10 && y >= column[j] && y <= column[j]+10) {
        alert(j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="myP" onmousedown="mouseDown()" >dff</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me further when the size is static. In my case the X and Y position was different. But I found a workarround and loop trough the array and save the values in two variables.